# Number of surjective functions from a set $\{1,2,\dots,k\} \to \{1,2,\dots,n\}$, I don't get a thing...

Tags: combinatorics, functions

Here is what I have, after a little introduction:

Let's calculate the number of surjective functions $f_k: \{1,2,\dots,k\} \to \{1,2,\dots,n\}$. We start observing that every function is surjective on its own image. Then if $n \ge 1$ and for each $j \in [1,n]\cap\mathbb{N}$  we denote with $A_j$ the class of all the functions $f_k: \{1,2,\dots,k\} \to \{1,2,\dots,n\}$ whose images have exactly $j$ elements. Then we have that

$n^k = |F_k^n| = \sum_{j=1}^{n}|A_j|$

Where $|F_k^n|$ is the number of strings of $k$ character that can be selected from an alphabet of $n$ items.

I don't get why that equality is true. Any idea?

Comment: Because the sets $A_j$ are disjoint, and their union is $F^n_k$.

Comment: I figured that the reason should have been that but I have difficulty understanding why the union of the $A_j$ is $F_n^k$

Comment: Because each function in $F_k^n$ has to have a range with _some_ number of elements. You are just summing over all possibilities for the size of the range of $f$.

Comment: Shouldn't his range have k elements? (Probably I misunderstood on this)

Comment: Ah, you are thinking of the _codomain_. The range (image) is the set of values which are actually attained as an output of $f$. For example, when $k=3,n=5$, and $f(1)=1,f(2)=4,f(3)=4$, then the range of $f$ is $\{1,4\}$.

Comment: I was thinking that by definition the function $f_k^n$ had k elements in its image but I seem to be wrong on this point.

Comment: EDIT: reading better your previous comment I think I got the point, thanks.